# jquery plugin - make ajax call chainable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, chaining

I am trying to write a jquery plugin.

Now, I would like to use an ajax-call in one of the functions of this plugin.

However it should be chainable, meaning in this case that the ajax-call should be executed and only after something was returned, the return should happen.

I tried different things but so far I could not make it so that the second function in the chain is really executed after the return value of the ajax call was retrieved;

In this version (see below) I can use

> $(document).createDatabase().message();

So, chaining works.
But looking at the console log – the message() function is executed before the ajax-call in createDatabase() is finished.

How can I make it so that

> $(document).createDatabase().message();

first returns the output/return of the ajax-call that is inside createDatabase() and only after that message() is executed?

Code:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.createDatabase = function(options) {

        // Plugin options defaults
        var settings = $.extend({
            name: 'NA',
            onExit: function() {} // callback function
        }, options);

        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "plugin/php/createDatabase.php",
                data: settings
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
             console.log("createDatabase executed with message: " + msg);
             settings.onExit.call();    
        });

      return this;

   };



   $.fn.message = function() {

       console.log('this should appear after the console-log message of createDatabase');
       return this;
   }

}(jQuery));
```

Thank You!

Comment: the `return this` will happen long before the ajax completes and `message()` will fire synchronously also. Are you trying to use your own plugin for message also or some third party plugin?

Comment: Yes – that is exactly the problem. I tried to put `return this` into the `.done` function of the ajax-call. But this does not seem to work since `this` is then referring to a different thing, right? `message` is just the second function of the plugin.

Comment: Should read and understand :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . You can't do what you are trying to do. Anything related to the ajax needs to be handled in callback or as promise of the ajax

Comment: Not really clear why you want the chained method for `messag()`. You could use it however in a callback option of the first plugin

Comment: its not so much about `message()` as it is about `createDatabase()` – I want to make that chainable, since it should create some database entries and I need to make sure that these are created before moving on – therefore being able to chain this would be wonderful.

Comment: Can't chain it by returning `this` which is the norm for all jQuery methods. You could return the `$.ajax` promise but would be unorthodox

Comment: also since example is using `document` as selector...does this really need to be used with an element? No need to do it on `$.fn` if it won;t be element specific. If it was just built in `$.createDatabase()` it wouldn't matter what you returned

Comment: Can't help a lot more without a much higher level overview of objectives updated in question

Comment: Thanks! I guess you are right – `$.createDatabase()` would suffice. The only objective I have is to make  `$.createDatabase()` chainable – but because of the ajax-call inside it I want to make it synchronous to that .. i.e. that the chain continues only after the ajax call was executed completely

Comment: have you not tried setting `async: false` on your ajax settings?

Comment: @swatkins `async:false` is being deprecated by browser vendors...and for good reason. It completely blocks the UI and all scripts  and that is why it has been recognized as terrible practice for a long time. try using it will see warnings in console in some browsers now

Comment: @charlietfl - I agree that `async:false` is not best practice. But the op is wanting to run an ajax request synchronously. This still stands as a viable option.

Comment: @swatkins not in light of deprecation it doesn't. Using a deprecated bad practice to circumvent something that should be handled differently in the first place doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl - not here to get in a philosophical debate on the use of deprecated options. I agree with you that you should not block the UI. However, the op's decision to block the UI is his/her decision and he/she assumes those risks. Therefore, until jQuery removes `async:false` as an option, this would work for the op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a couple of things, but they are all a bad idea. The reason is that these are two separate jQuery plugins - a plugin should be capable of working on its own. There is no guarantee or reason that somebody won't do `.message().createDatabase()`. If you need to guarantee the order of execution, then you should use just one plugin. One possible way would be to pass `message` inside `options` when you call `.createDatabase(options)`, and then run `message` when the call is done. Like so

```
$(document).createDatabase({
    message: function() {...}
});
...
var promise = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "plugin/php/createDatabase.php",
            data: settings
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
         console.log("createDatabase executed with message: " + msg);
         settings.onExit.call();    
    });
...
if ( settings.message )
    promise.done( settings.message.bind(this) );
```

> I tried different things but so far I could not make it so that the second function in the chain is really executed after the return value of the ajax call was retrieved;

The second function executes when the first one finishes. The first one finishes with `return this`, but this happens before the ajax call is done because ajax calls are asynchronous.